# Gather web data for ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode4.5

Is there a way to make an app compile data from a website? I need to make an app that will display a name, address and some short details - but I need this information to be regularly updated and contributed to by admins, without requiring me to continually add the new information into the app.
I have not done an app of this kind before so any help or assistance would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly two types of web service available

1. SOAP
2. REST.

Use the  parsing technique (XML parsing,JSON parsing) depends on the type of web service to parse the data.
The information will be updated automatically in your application when ever some change in the web service happens.
I hope you will get some idea.

Comment: Thanks for that, I had the right idea but couldnt get the right terms! Game on...

Comment: Check these links 1.http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/call-soap-web-service-from-iphone/ 2.http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/09/parsing-xml-in-an-iphone-app-tutorial/ 3.http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service

Comment: You will get some better idea after going through those links